# ADC with small input range

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc

All of the ADCs I found online have an input range on the order of few volts, e.g. 0 to 5 or -4 to +4. But my signal is in the mV range. Are there any ADCs with such a small input range? I know I can add an op amp but if I can avoid that it will be better.

Edit: required resolution is 16 bits, sampling rate is 300 ksps.

Comment: I doubt it. You want to amplify it anyways to make it more immune to noise on its way to and inside the ADC.

Comment: The amplification does not increase the SNR so how does that help?

Comment: Amplification will increase the effective resolution of the ADC. Without amplification, a signal "in the mV range" will only give you two or three bits of resolution with typical ADCs.

Comment: @student1 The noise at the signal source is not the only noise that will always be in the signal. Just because there are no rats in the wheat when it leaves the farm doesn't mean there won't be rats in the wheat by the time it gets to the mill.

Comment: It is extremely difficult (read expensive) to make an ADC with microvolt resolution - it is much more cost-effective to make the ADC with inputs in the volt range and amplify the signal externally to the level required by the ADC. The amplifying device does not have to make the compromises that would be required if it was implemented within the ADC device so it can have a lower noise level.

Comment: 16-bits at 300ksps might be asking a bit much. Do you actually require 16-bit resolution? It's not trivial to make a PCB for 16-bit resolution ADCs and your signal is only a few mV plus noise to begin with.

Comment: inside an ADC is one or more analog comparators; driving the inputs to such comparators with large voltages (up to volts) is crucial in achieving fast decisions. How wouild a 16-bit ADC with +-100 millivolt input range be designed? By amplifying the input by 20, to +- 2 volts. Thus I think you should use the same idea in your circuit. Install a 26dB DC amplifier.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Using dB for DC gain is painful. Not wrong, just painful.

Comment: 16 bit over a "mV range" is what specialized test equipment like the Keithley 2182A nanovoltmeter can do, at less than 20 samples per seconds.So your implementation details (op amp vs. not) do not matter at all, you are at a dead end and need to find a completely different way of solving your original problem.

Comment: I was about to suggest HX711 until I saw your speed requirement. You need an amplifier.

Answer (score 1):

You really did not tell us anything about the ADC specs that you require. Various manufacturers like Analog Devices and TI have vast lines of products, including integrated parts that have PGA (programmable gain amplifier) front ends.

Here is a copy and paste from A TI webpage with a full scale input range in hundreds of millivolts.

"**The ADS111x perform conversions at data rates up to 860 samples per second (SPS). The PGA offers input ranges from ±256 mV to ±6.144 V, allowing precise large- and small-signal measurements. The ADS1115 features an input multiplexer (MUX) that allows two differential or four single-ended input measurements. Use the digital comparator in the ADS1114 and ADS1115 for under- and overvoltage detection.**"

Don't give up yet. Keep searching. There are tons of devices out there.

Linear Technology was bought out by Analog Devices so it has a huge product line.

TI has been buying companies for years like Burr Brown and National Semiconductor so it;s product line is extremely large as well.

Here is the link for the TI product;
[TI ADC](http://www.ti.com/product/ADS1115)

Again, you did not mention what, speed, resolution, etc. that you need so the above example may or may not be of interest to you.

Hope this helps a bit .....